# How to render from inside an object in THREE.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to render, from inside an objecte to a texture (to store some values). I need to put the camera in the middle but when i render from that camera, to test if it works properly, i don't see any part of the object, in the render.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287186/is-there-a-backface-visibility-equivalent-for-three-js

Comment: it could be that your object is to close to the camera and the `near` value of your camera is to big

Comment: i could be rendered from one side only.

Comment: @marcel yes, thanks it was that it was rendered from one side only.