# Only render visible objects

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js

I'm trying to render a world with very many blocks, but the performance has become very bad.
So I was wondering if there is a possibility to only render objects / object faces that are visible for the camera and aren't covered by other blocks.

Here is the code I use for creating the world

```
for (let x = 0 ; x < this.worldWidth; x++){
    for (let z = 0; z < this.worldWidth; z++){
        let y = this.getNoiseY(x, z)

        let grassblock = new Block(BlockID.GRASS_BLOCK)
        grassblock.setPosition(x - this.worldWidth / 2, y, z - this.worldWidth / 2)
    }
}
```

Every block has a BoxBufferGeometry and a MeshStandardMaterial.
Are there any ways to optimize those performance issues?

Comment: This might help a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287186/is-there-a-backface-visibility-equivalent-for-three-js

Comment: @Cerbrus Thank you, I feel like the performance is a bit better, nevertheless blocks are rendered even if they are covered by other blocks and this is the major issue I guess

Comment: What you're looking for is "occlusion culling." I do not believe three.js offers built-in occlusion culling, so you would have to implement it yourself. There are a couple different ways to achieve this, so you might not get a detailed answer here. Research the topic and try to make it work, and if you get stuck, come back and ask more questions.